# Greenhopper: only useful if you buy the whole Agile package?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I work in a remote company where email, forums and IM are key communication tools. We don't formally follow any book-methodology but *have* been evolving towards a more agile-style setup in terms of release schedules, client interaction and a sort of scrum adapted for distributed teams.

We use Jira on one project and I wondered if Greenhopper might be of use. Or, whether it is focused on teams who adhere much more formally to the entire Agile dogma, and would end up getting in the way?

I don't want to get into a discussion on if Agile is good or bad, what it involves, etc... just whether Greenhopper is useful to projects whose methodology is inspired by Agile principles rather than defined by them.

Comment: better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hey Jeff. There's so many darn sites now, how's a girl to choose? :)

Answer (score 1):

GreenHopper is pretty flexible. I've seen marketing teams, operations teams plus more using the task board to track their work in progress without any real though to 'agile'. Give it a shot and let me know how you get on.

Thanks,
Nicholas Muldoon
GreenHopper Product Manager

Answer (score -2):

I won't comment on Greenhopper, since I don't have recent experience regarding it.

Many tools are designed based on a "pure agile" model. That is, for a single team, working on a single thing for or a single product owner.

However, in my experience the vast majority of real-world organizations – even the very small – have a more complex landscape they need to manage. Often, even a single freelance developer has a load of things to work on: the active project(s), leads for new projects, maintenance of old projects, and so on. And simple tools that have a pure-scrum-one-team-works-on-a-single-thing-at-a-time just won’t cut it…

Agilefant is IMHO, while complient with "the agile dogma", also pretty flexible with respect to how people can be assigned to multiple things. Also, it's quite flexible in terms how different types of work can be modeled into it (that is, there's no need to conduct every project as Sprints, and so on).

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm Agilefant's product owner.

Comment: This reads too much like an advertisement for your company, and doesn't answer the OP's question.  You have done this a number of times now.  Please stop it.

Comment: Sorry! I got a bit carried away seeing so many threads asking about good agile tools. There's no company behind Agilefant, at least not yet.

Comment: Tried to edit my answer to better answer the original question.